# Port Knocking using only Iptables/netfilter

Tags: iptables

I am using the following iptables rules for port knocking. Everything works well, but it open the port for just a second and then close it. So how to improve this script to accept connection for a 30 seconds for example ?

```
#!/bin/sh

iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -Z

iptables -N STATE0
iptables -A STATE0 -p udp --dport 12345 -m recent --name KNOCK1 --set -j DROP
iptables -A STATE0 -j DROP

iptables -N STATE1
iptables -A STATE1 -m recent --name KNOCK1 --remove
iptables -A STATE1 -p udp --dport 23456 -m recent --name KNOCK2 --set -j DROP
iptables -A STATE1 -j STATE0

iptables -N STATE2
iptables -A STATE2 -m recent --name KNOCK2 --remove
iptables -A STATE2 -p udp --dport 34567 -m recent --name KNOCK3 --set -j DROP
iptables -A STATE2 -j STATE0

iptables -N STATE3
iptables -A STATE3 -m recent --name KNOCK3 --remove
iptables -A STATE3 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A STATE3 -j STATE0

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -m recent --name KNOCK3 --rcheck -j STATE3
iptables -A INPUT -m recent --name KNOCK2 --rcheck -j STATE2
iptables -A INPUT -m recent --name KNOCK1 --rcheck -j STATE1
iptables -A INPUT -j STATE0
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using [this howto](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/implement_port_knocking_using_iptables.html). You may want to look at [this howto](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Port_Knocking#Port_Knocking_with_iptables_only) instead. The key issue here is that you're using the `--set` parameter in conjunction with `-m recent`, whereas the linked howto is using `--rcheck`.  With `--rcheck`, you can specify the `--seconds` parameter to specify a length of time. It would probably be a good idea to review the parameters for the [**recent** patch](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html#ss3.16)